# How to migrate SQL data and keep SP's

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have two databases `LIVE` and `DEVEL`. I am currently working in `DEVEL` and have created and modified a number of stored procedures however I am running out of test data so I need to find a way to copy data from `LIVE` to `DEVEL` but I don't want to lose my stored procedures.

I am using SQL Server 2008 Management Studio and have tried `Tasks -> Export Data`. I then pick `Drop and recreate new destination tables` however I get errors like:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Currency_Rate'. Cannot insert
>   duplicate key in object 'dbo.Currency_Rate'.

So it is not dropping and recreating the tables.

I need to migrate data from `LIVE` to `DEVEL` quite often but haven't yet found a way of doing it and this is holding me back because I cannot test the implemented functionality.

Could anyone out there experienced enough in the matter point me in the right direction? I am not interested in paid third party tools like RedGate SQL Compare so please do not suggest them

Comment: Do you want to move all the data in the database, or just several tables?

Comment: Ideally all the tables because they are all linked - I tried particular tables but it failed because of PK and FK links

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would ensure all my SP's are scripted off into files I can re-run on demand.

There are comparison tools within VS which allow you to script off changes, or you can manually go into the DEVEL database, expand the `Programmability` > `Stored Procedures` node, right click you new SP's and select `Script Stored Procedure` > `Create to` > `File` and save it somewhere sensible with your project.

Assuming this is the case, if you simply restore your LIVE database over the top of your DEVEL DB you can re-run your SP scripts on DEVEL and this will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Execute this query for your tables, copy output data and run it's on another database.

**Query:**

```
DECLARE 
      @TableName SYSNAME
    , @ObjectID INT
    , @IsImportIdentity BIT = 1

DECLARE [tables] CURSOR READ_ONLY FAST_FORWARD LOCAL FOR 
    SELECT 
          '[' + s.name + '].[' + t.name + ']'
        , t.[object_id]
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT
              t.[schema_id]
            , t.[object_id]
            , t.name
        FROM sys.objects t WITH (NOWAIT)
        JOIN sys.partitions p WITH (NOWAIT) ON p.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
        WHERE p.[rows] > 0
            AND t.[type] = 'U'
    ) t
    JOIN sys.schemas s WITH (NOWAIT) ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
    WHERE t.name IN ('<your table name>')

OPEN [tables]

FETCH NEXT FROM [tables] INTO 
      @TableName
    , @ObjectID

DECLARE 
      @SQLInsert NVARCHAR(MAX)
    , @SQLColumns NVARCHAR(MAX)
    , @SQLTinyColumns NVARCHAR(MAX)

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

    SELECT 
          @SQLInsert = ''
        , @SQLColumns = ''
        , @SQLTinyColumns = ''

    ;WITH cols AS 
    (
        SELECT 
              c.name
            , datetype = t.name
            , c.column_id
        FROM sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT)
        JOIN sys.types t WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.system_type_id = t.system_type_id AND c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
        WHERE c.[object_id] = @ObjectID
            AND (c.is_identity = 0 OR @IsImportIdentity = 1)
            AND c.is_computed = 0
            AND t.name NOT IN ('xml', 'geography', 'geometry', 'hierarchyid')
    )
    SELECT 
          @SQLInsert = 'INSERT INTO ' + @TableName + ' (' + STUFF((
            SELECT ', [' + c.name + ']'
            FROM cols c
            ORDER BY c.column_id
            FOR XML PATH, TYPE, ROOT).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') + ')'
        , @SQLTinyColumns = STUFF((
            SELECT ', ' + c.name
            FROM cols c
            ORDER BY c.column_id
            FOR XML PATH, TYPE, ROOT).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')
        , @SQLColumns = STUFF((SELECT CHAR(13) +
            CASE 
                WHEN c.datetype = 'uniqueidentifier' 
                    THEN ' + '', '' + ISNULL('''''''' + CAST([' + c.name + '] AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '''''''', ''NULL'')' 
                WHEN c.datetype IN ('nvarchar', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'char', 'varbinary', 'binary') 
                    THEN ' + '', '' + ISNULL('''''''' + CAST(REPLACE([' + c.name + '], '''''''', '''''''''''' ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '''''''', ''NULL'')' 
                WHEN c.datetype = 'datetime'
                    THEN ' + '', '' + ISNULL('''''''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, [' + c.name + '], 120) + '''''''', ''NULL'')' 
                ELSE 
                ' + '', '' + ISNULL(CAST([' + c.name + '] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), ''NULL'')'
            END
            FROM cols c
            ORDER BY c.column_id
            FOR XML PATH, TYPE, ROOT).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 10, 'CHAR(13) + '', ('' +')

    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '    
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE 
          @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''''
        , @x INT = 1
        , @count INT = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ' + @TableName + ')

    IF EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM tempdb.dbo.sysobjects
        WHERE ID = OBJECT_ID(''tempdb..#import'')
    )
        DROP TABLE #import;

    SELECT ' + @SQLTinyColumns + ', ''RowNumber'' = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ' + @SQLTinyColumns + ')
    INTO #import
    FROM ' + @TableName + ' 

    WHILE @x < @count BEGIN

        SELECT @SQL = ''VALUES '' + STUFF((
        SELECT ' + @SQLColumns + ' + '')''' + '
        FROM #import 
        WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN @x AND @x + 9
        FOR XML PATH, TYPE, ROOT).value(''.'', ''NVARCHAR(MAX)''), 1, 2, CHAR(13) + '' '') + '';''

        PRINT(''' + @SQLInsert + ''')
        PRINT(@SQL)

        SELECT @x = @x + 10

    END'

    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL

    FETCH NEXT FROM [tables] INTO 
          @TableName
        , @ObjectID

END

CLOSE [tables]
DEALLOCATE [tables]
```

**Output:**

```
INSERT INTO [Person].[Address] ([AddressID], [AddressLine1], [AddressLine2], [City], [StateProvinceID], [PostalCode], [rowguid], [ModifiedDate])
VALUES 
  (1, '1970 Napa Ct.', NULL, 'Bothell', 79, '98011', '9AADCB0D-36CF-483F-84D8-585C2D4EC6E9', '2002-01-04 00:00:00')
, (2, '9833 Mt. Dias Blv.', NULL, 'Bothell', 79, '98011', '32A54B9E-E034-4BFB-B573-A71CDE60D8C0', '2003-01-01 00:00:00')
, (3, '7484 Roundtree Drive', NULL, 'Bothell', 79, '98011', '4C506923-6D1B-452C-A07C-BAA6F5B142A4', '2007-04-08 00:00:00')
, (4, '9539 Glenside Dr', NULL, 'Bothell', 79, '98011', 'E5946C78-4BCC-477F-9FA1-CC09DE16A880', '2003-03-07 00:00:00')
, (5, '1226 Shoe St.', NULL, 'Bothell', 79, '98011', 'FBAFF937-4A97-4AF0-81FD-B849900E9BB0', '2003-01-20 00:00:00')
, (6, '1399 Firestone Drive', NULL, 'Bothell', 79, '98011', 'FEBF8191-9804-44C8-877A-33FDE94F0075', '2003-03-17 00:00:00')
, (7, '5672 Hale Dr.', NULL, 'Bothell', 79, '98011', '0175A174-6C34-4D41-B3C1-4419CD6A0446', '2004-01-12 00:00:00')
, (8, '6387 Scenic Avenue', NULL, 'Bothell', 79, '98011', '3715E813-4DCA-49E0-8F1C-31857D21F269', '2003-01-18 00:00:00')
, (9, '8713 Yosemite Ct.', NULL, 'Bothell', 79, '98011', '268AF621-76D7-4C78-9441-144FD139821A', '2006-07-01 00:00:00')
, (10, '250 Race Court', NULL, 'Bothell', 79, '98011', '0B6B739D-8EB6-4378-8D55-FE196AF34C04', '2003-01-03 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO [Person].[Address] ([AddressID], [AddressLine1], [AddressLine2], [City], [StateProvinceID], [PostalCode], [rowguid], [ModifiedDate])
VALUES 
  (11, '1318 Lasalle Street', NULL, 'Bothell', 79, '98011', '981B3303-ACA2-49C7-9A96-FB670785B269', '2007-04-01 00:00:00')
, (12, '5415 San Gabriel Dr.', NULL, 'Bothell', 79, '98011', '1C2C9CFE-AB9F-4F96-8E1F-D9666B6F7F22', '2007-02-06 00:00:00')
, (13, '9265 La Paz', NULL, 'Bothell', 79, '98011', 'E0BA2F52-C907-4553-A0DB-67FC67D28AE4', '2008-01-15 00:00:00')
, (14, '8157 W. Book', NULL, 'Bothell', 79, '98011', 'A1C658AE-C553-4A9D-A081-A550D39B64DF', '2004-01-05 00:00:00')
, (15, '4912 La Vuelta', NULL, 'Bothell', 79, '98011', 'F397E64A-A9D8-4E57-9E7C-B10928ACADD6', '2007-12-20 00:00:00')
, (16, '40 Ellis St.', NULL, 'Bothell', 79, '98011', '0312B65F-CB60-4396-9EC7-A78B2EAC1A1B', '2006-12-11 00:00:00')
, (17, '6696 Anchor Drive', NULL, 'Bothell', 79, '98011', 'CE9B3B47-9267-4727-BCD2-687C47482C06', '2007-12-10 00:00:00')
, (18, '1873 Lion Circle', NULL, 'Bothell', 79, '98011', '963854F7-E3CB-46A1-A3DB-1B05F71D6473', '2008-01-01 00:00:00')
, (19, '3148 Rose Street', NULL, 'Bothell', 79, '98011', '6B7ACB0F-CDBF-44FD-BA14-EB08A56C1582', '2008-05-04 00:00:00')
, (20, '6872 Thornwood Dr.', NULL, 'Bothell', 79, '98011', '4B1F1ED4-97A4-43FD-BB1E-9E05817718E8', '2003-03-09 00:00:00');
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply. I kind of understand what the code does but can you explain in a bit more detail what exactly it does and why use this approach?

Comment: This query simply generate insert statement for any table, what's your specify in filter condition. For example, I add result for `AdwentureWorks.Person.Address`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to make a copy of your database, make a backup of the database (Right click on database --> `Tasks` --> `Back Up...`), then restore it (Right click on `Databases` --> `Restore Database...`

Comment: But that would overwrite all the data including views SP's etc so it is not an option. I want to keep all the SP's in DEVEL and only migrate the data from LIVe

Answer (score 0):

I would prepare SSIS task for the job.

As a first step for each task I would ensure that data is removed from destination tables, then I would copy data.